# Escape an PL/pgSQL variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have an trigger on PostgreSQL 9 like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clients_update_billingdata_trigger()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  columnsUpdate  TEXT;
BEGIN
   columnsUpdate := '';

   IF (NEW.rsocial IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.rsocial) THEN
      columnsUpdate := columnsUpdate || 'RSocial before: ' || OLD.rsocial || '. RSocial after: ' || NEW.rsocial || E'\n';
   END IF;

   IF (NEW.legalidentifier IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.legalidentifier) THEN
      columnsUpdate := columnsUpdate || 'ILegal before: ' || OLD.legalidentifier || '. ILegal after: ' || NEW.legalidentifier || E'\n';
   END IF;

   [...]

   IF (columnsUpdate != '') THEN
      SELECT dblink_exec ('dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxxxx',
                          'INSERT INTO BillingDataUpdate (client_id, columnsupdate)
                           VALUES (''' || NEW.idclient || ''', ''' || columnsUpdate || ''');');
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;
 END;
 $BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The values of `NEW.rsocial` can be, for example: *Tommy's service*. If I turn off the trigger, the record is saved correctly (in the `other` table, in Clients) because I escape the string in PHP with `pg_escape_string` function. The question is, how escape `NEW.rsocial` to run the trigger?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions `quote_literal` and `quote_nullable` might be useful. But beware, that these are PostgreSQL functions, so make sure the other side of the DBLINK understands the result.

You might also take a look at this part of the docs:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE

**EDIT**

The `quote_xyz` must not be applied to the usages of `rsocial` but to the `dblink_exec`.

```
  SELECT dblink_exec ('dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxxxx',
                      'INSERT INTO BillingDataUpdate (client_id, columnsupdate) '
                       || 'VALUES (' || quote_nullable(NEW.idclient) || ', ' 
                       || quote_nullable(columnsUpdate) || ');');
```

And please note the changed number of `'` in the string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks @A.H. but I tested these functions before asking, but "don't work"

Comment: @doctore: Can you clarify: What _exactly_ did you try and what was the error? Code and examples would help most.

Comment: @doctore: "*don't work*" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Comment: @doctore: It is also important to know what database is at the other end of the dblink. PostgreSQL? Or anything else?

Comment: ERROR: A character string in quotes is inconclusive at or near "'previous RSocial: test. RSocial new: rsocial test'
'); "
CONTEXT: Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute command. In this case RSocial = rsocial test'

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right, when I use these functions the error is the same as when I don't. I put this error in a previous comment.

Comment: @A.H. the other database is in the same PostgreSQL 9.0 server. The problem is that the dblink does not run due to error I have written in an earlier comment

Comment: @doctore: The part with dblink error is clear. But what was the code you have tried using `quote_xyz`?

Comment: @A.H. columnsUpdate := columnsUpdate || 'RSocial before: ' || OLD.rsocial || '. RSocial after: ' || quote_xyz(NEW.rsocial) || E'\n';

Comment: @A.H. Thanks. I found another posibility that works (columnsUpdate := replace(columnsUpdate, E'''', E'''''');) but your solution is better.

Answer (score 2):

Although this post already has an accepted answer, I would suggest using [the `FORMAT` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-string.html):

`FORMAT(E'%s', YOUR_VARIABLE)`